# VREPRINT doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell

According to the [GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Editing-Characters.html#index-VREPRINT), there is a character [`VREPRINT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Editing-Characters.html#index-VREPRINT), or `rprnt`, which is supposed to re-print the shell's line-editor's input buffer. This can be helpful if something like a background process has written to the PTY
while you're typing another command and there is output interspersed with your input. However, I tried actually using it, and it seems to have no effect. I did the following:

1. Run a `sh` session on the latest `alpine` image from Dockerhub.
2. Use `stty` to bind the `rprnt` character to `^N`.
3. Type some input
4. From a separate session, write to the first session's PTY.
5. Try pressing ctrl-N to reprint my input

[image]

I expected it to refresh my input and remove the output that was written. However, there was no effect. There is still output cluttering my line editor. I verified that `icanon` and `iexten` are set on this PTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your shell is `bash` or some other shell with full-featured line editing capabilities.

These shells, while waiting for you to type the command, set the tty mode to raw rather than canonical, hence the `rprnt` setting doesn't apply to them.

The command line tool `stty` doesn't report it back since these shells toggle the settings back and forth for the duration of line editing vs. running the requested external program (such as `stty` itself). You can confirm this by running `stty -a < /dev/pts/[this-terminal's-number]` from another terminal while this one is at the prompt.

Pick a program that does *not* have full-blown line editing capabilities, such as `cat`, `dash` or alike. You'll find that issuing `stty rprnt ^N` upfront, and pressing `^N` does indeed reprint the given line. At least I've verified and it works for me.

For shells with powerful line editing capabilities, you'll have to consult the given shell's documentation (or in case of `bash` it's the `readline` library) to see how to reprint the prompt or how to configure its hotkey.